read Speed and engine RPM from bluetooth device with web bluetooth
I am tired to connect my ECU Car for read speed and Engine RPM over Bluetooth Device with web Bluetooth...
i used OBDII ELM327 V2.1 hardware
many software can using this device but that software's are android apk
is it possible to read speed or Engine RPM with web Bluetooth ?
